# How to resolve a freeze (or deadlock) in ntdll.dll?

Tags: .net, udp, freeze

I have an application running on the .Net framework 4 and my application runs managed AND unmanaged code. In the unmanaged code, UDP sockets are used. When the application is run from Visual Studio, all is fine, but when it is run on its own, it often freezes. I have seen the behavior on both Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7 SP1. When I attach the debugger to the application and pause it, I can see that many MANY threads are stuck at the same memory address in ntdll.dll. When disassembled, the netdll.dll command executing is "ret".

Does that ring a bell for anyone ?

It seems there has previously been similar issues, such as reported here, and it was related to UDP:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/1b54b2f2-6e7c-405b-bdda-62197ac8a287
No answers were ever given.

I have also found an old hotfix for a similar issue, but according to Microsoft it only applies to Windows NT 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: blocking or nonblocking mode? previous error codes?

Answer (score 4):

It is not the operating system that is causing the deadlock.  Yes, your stack trace will show it blocking on KiFastSystemCallRet() inside ntdll.dll.  With the stack trace pointing to the RET instruction after SYSENTER.  But it merely is doing what you asked it to do.

Use the Debug + Windows + Threads window to see what your threads are doing.  The classic deadlock scenario is that one of the threads has acquired the synchronization object and is blocking.  The synchronization object that another thread is trying to acquire.  This is one of the most common threading headaches.

Comment: I agree Hans - that it runs fine in the debugger would tend to indicate that some task is being serialized differently (e.g. by performing debug output) averting what would then be a deadlock.

Comment: The problem I have is then when I look at the stack traces, all I see are calls within Microsoft DLLs (with the root AND the tip both in ntdll.dll), which obviously makes it hard to figure out where it comes from in my code. Also, when attaching to the running process, I have to attach using the Native option, because the call stacks aren't in managed code.

Comment: You are not going to be able to debug this if you can't get the debugger attached in managed mode.  It's not normal and you haven't provided any info that would let us guess why the debugger doesn't offer the option.

Comment: Sorry, I badly worded that. I CAN attach to my app using the Managed option, but I can't pause it then to see what's happening because I get a pop-up from Visual Studio that the type of the code that I'm trying to break into is different from the type I've elected to debug.

Comment: Anybody know what's the difference between running a debug application from within Visual Studio and running a debug application by double-clicking it ? That might give me a good hint.